# Android convert ImageIcon to Drawable

Tags: android, drawable, imageicon

I'm making an app that take datas from a database and it should take an ImageIcon. How can I use that class in Android and convert it to Drawable to show it in app?

It's not from a resource file. It's from an ImageIcon as variable of an object i receive from database.

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320725/how-do-i-convert-an-imageicon-to-bitmapdrawable-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Drawable from resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818118/how-to-create-drawable-from-resource)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/images/image.png");
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```